# Power Automate and (exotic) email/domain extensions

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Created a Power Automate (flow) that sends out emails to users.

However users with a .group domain extension in their email address (ex. user@contoso.group) do not receive the emails.

Other users of the same email do receive the email (and see the correct .group emails in the CC of the email). So the Power Automate ran correctly.

ICT claims not to find anything in the logs of their Exchange, spam filter, virus scanner.

Would it be possible that the Power platform blocks sending out emails to certain/new domain extensions?

Answer (score 0):

I think creating proper data loss policy might help in this situation.

- Refer this link for more details.
- [Create a data loss prevention (DLP) policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/create-dlp-policy?source=recommendations)